# Visual questions for 6th graders

Tags: secondary-education, primary-education, arithmetic-operations

I'm tutoring a 6th grader in math at the moment and because she never has a ton of homework I like to give her some interesting extra problems to do.  It seems she really enjoyed a problem I showed her the other day where we counted up how many ways there were of getting between two points in a city without actually counting them all up.

I think the thing she really liked about it was that we had a picture in front of us (a roadmap for a madeup town with ridiculously few roads) and could use some simple math to conclude things about it.

Are there any other visual problems like this that you guys recommend that only involve arithmetic skills (preferably involving fractions or decimals so that she gets some more practice with those)?  Or is there a website or book that has several of these types of problems?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but may be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/733754/18398

Comment: Also not an answer, but also may be useful:  http://mathoverflow.net/q/8846/12357

Answer (score 3):

Highly recommend the Anne Joshua books - Enrich-e-matics.
She has things like balance scales to solve equations (using shapes), with fractions she draws out the bars and labels them very well. 
They start from easy to hard and Book two is an extension of book one.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Math Munch blog](http://mathmunch.org/). Their subtitle is A Weekly Digest of the Mathematical Internet, but I think they originally focused on middle school. You might try looking under their [puzzles tag](http://mathmunch.org/tag/puzzles/).